# PHP convert two arrays together

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert two arrays into only one array, that I can later on use to insert into a database.

The arrays looks like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Player1' (length=7)
  1 => string 'Player2' (length=7)
  2 => string 'Player3' (length=7)
  3 => string 'Player4' (length=7)

array (size=4)
  0 => string '43' (length=2)
  1 => string '12' (length=2)
  2 => string '65' (length=2)
  3 => string '12' (length=2)
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
array (size=4)
  name => string 'Player1' (length=7)
  value => string '43' (length=2)

  name => string 'Player2' (length=7)
  value => string '12' (length=2)

  name => string 'Player3' (length=7)
  value => string '65' (length=2)

  name => string 'Player4' (length=7)
  value => string '12' (length=2)
```

A little code:

```
$players = "Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4";
$values = "43,12,65,12";

$players = explode(',',$players);
$values = explode(',',$values);
```

I have tried with `array_combine`, but that seems to remove duplicates. It removed the value 12.

Comment: Have you tried `array_merge()` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the arrays and push the combined elements onto the new array.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($players as $i => $player) {
    $new_array[] = array('name' => $player, 'value' => $values[$i]);
}
```

You could also use `array_map`:

```
$new_array = array_map(function($p, $v) { 
    return array('name' => $p, 'value' => $v); 
    }, $players, $values);
```

Comment: array_map(), identical to mine down to arg names and whitespace!  Oh wait, I used $result instead of $new_array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$players = "Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4";
$values = "43,12,65,12";

$players = explode(',',$players);
$values = explode(',',$values);

$newArr=array();
foreach ($players as $i => $val) {
    $newArr[] = array($val, $values[$i]);
}

print_r($newArr);
```

I don't think this is most elegant decision, though... And I'm sure this kind of answers already present in Stackoverflow....